# Append Div text to an input value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an `input` value for an email address. I then have an email address on the site in a `div`, I want to append the `div` to the `input` value so the `input` value is the same as the `div`. The user can then submit this.

I have tried:

```js
$('#input_2').append($('.emailaddress').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_2" id="input_email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
<div class="emailaddress">test@test.com</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the problem?

Comment: I have added above

Comment: it should be `$('#input_email')`instead of `$('#input_2')` as `input_2` is the `name`, not the `id`

Comment: You should change the `value` attribute of the input element and not "add" a textnode to it (which would produce invalid markup because `<input />` elements don't have children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **$('#input_2')** it is name not id so **DOM** will not able to find it.
use this. input have **val** property. and because you are using class so it will return array.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#input_email').val($('.emailaddress')[0].innerText);
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#input_email').val($('.emailaddress')[0].innerText);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="input_2" id="input_email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email Address">

<div class="emailaddress">test@test.com</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *DOM will not able to find it* - slightly misleading.   *jquery* can still find it using the name, just not using `#` for id.    You also don't need `[0]` as `.text()` will combine all values and there's only 1.

Comment: @freeedomn i understand your point but i just explained what he written in his question. For [0] i am precisely selecting first element.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this with jquery

```
<script>
var email = $('.emailaddress').html();

$('#input_email').val(email);
</script>
```

// add this near the end of you page before the body
 // and the jquery reference in the header

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the help of an event.

```
$("#input_2").change(function () {
  $(".emailaddress").html($(#input_2).val());
});
```

Comment: It's supposed to be the other way around ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will help you.

```js
$('#input_email').val($('.emailaddress').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_2" id="input_email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
<div class="emailaddress">test@test.com</div>
```